# Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment on Evaluate function

Tags: excel, vba, compiler-errors

I'm sure this is something obvious but I haven't gotten it yet. Here is my code:

```
Sub Grossbypercent()

Dim GrossWeight As Double
Dim i As Long
Dim Val As Long
Dim div(2 To 250) As Variant
Dim x As Long


GrossWeight = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("H2:H250"))

For x = 2 To 250

Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B2:B250") = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Range("Sheet2!A$2:A$250"), Cells(x, 9), Range("H$2:H$250"))

Next x

For i = 2 To 250

    Val = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 2)
    div(i) = Evaluate(Val & "/" & GrossWeight)
    
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 3) = div(i) * Range("O2").Value
    
    On Error Resume Next
  
Next i

End Sub
```

I get the titled error on the Evaluate line, before which the code works fine and outputs as requested. I'm going to warrant a guess that I'm declaring something incorrectly, but I'm not sure what, any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using `Evaluate` at all? Why not just `Val / GrossWeight`?

Comment: @Rory You're right, now that I think about it, but now I get an overflow error on the same line without the Evaluate.

Comment: Definitely on that line, not the one before?

Comment: Is this someting you want?:  `Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B2:B250") = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Range("Sheet2!A$2:A$250"), Cells(x, 9), Range("H$2:H$250"))`  You are updating whole range with a fixed value in each iteration.

Comment: @Rory The line reads as div(i) = Val/GrossWeight debug is showing the error on that line but why would Val throw overflow there is nothing declared that would exceed Long

Comment: Also avoid using [VAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/val-function) as a variable :)

Comment: Okay so it was me just being dumb, 0/0 returns overflow.. I didin't know that, but here it is..